# iOS SQLite file save not persitent

Tags: ios, sqlite

I'm working on Xcode 6, Objective-C. I'm trying to use SQLite to store my datas. But I have a problem, the storage is not persitant. 
When I start my program, I have this in my dataBase file :

> id = 0; money = 1000000; name = xx;
>
> id = 1; money = 500200; name = bb;

Now when I insert a new data in the table and I check I have 3 rows. But when I close my app and I reopen it I still has 2 rows.

Here is some code, this is my init function :

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self){

        [self CopyDbToDocumentsFolder];

        if (sqlite3_open([[[self GetDocumentDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Bank.sqlite"]  UTF8String],
                         &_database) != SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"Failed to open database!");
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

And here is my insert function :

```
-(void)insert:(NSString *)cols withValues:(NSString *)values into:(NSString *) table{

    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO %@ (%@) VALUES(%@)", table, cols, values];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE);
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Failed to delete!");
        sqlite3_errmsg(_database);
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[self CopyDbToDocumentsFolder];`

Looks like you are copying the DB from your bundle to the documents directory every time you init that object. So when you start the app again, you're overwriting your database.

You only want to copy the database over if it's not already there.

Comment: Thanks it was that. You save my day.